# How to implement custom jackson object mappers

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm working on adapting [angular-ui-tree](http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/tree.html) to persist the tree structure in a one-to-many entity model.  The piece I am missing is how to have Spring/Jackson interpret the following POST body

```
data: "{
          "id":1.7976931348623157e+308,
          "name":"New Category -- Need Name",
          "parent":6,
          "type":"create"
       }"
```

that is serialized and delivered using a `$http` service method in Angular:

```
$http.post("/rest/category",
            {data: angular.toJson(updateData)}
        )
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            return [data, status];
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            return [data, status];
        })
```

Right now, I only get error 405s with the address, with the return value stating that

```
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

So, I modified the controller below to take in a `DummyCategory` object from the RequestBody:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/category", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public List<Category> createCategory(@RequestBody DummyCategory data ){
    log.info("Start creating category " + data);
}
```

which is this entity:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DummyCategoryDeserializer.class)
public class DummyCategory {
  private String type;
  private String name;
  private Long id;
  private int parent;

  //getters and setters
}
```

and corresponding `DummyCategoryDeserializer` class:

```
public class DummyCategoryDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DummyCategory> {

  @Override
  public DummyCategory deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
    String tempData = jp.getText();

    DummyCategory dummyCategory = new DummyCategory();
    return dummyCategory;
  }
}
```

Since I am very new at this, my goal is to have a debugger breakpoint set at the deserializer method and work my way through the properties.  However, after making these custom modifications, the `$http` service is still returning 405s on execution, and the breakpoints are not being hit.

I know that the server is functional, because all GET requests are returning expected values.

If you want to see the actual source code for this question, it is available on the [category-taxonomy](https://bitbucket.org/daredevil82/jasonjohns.com/src/838d031a2e25e83080fcc5a64933127db8ed126b/backend/src/main/java/com/jasonjohns/?at=feature/category-taxonomy) branch.  The new deserializer classes are within /models and /utils

Comment: Why are you writing a custom deserializer instead of just letting Jackson map it automatically?

Comment: Your AJAX call is using `PUT`.

Comment: Not the one I'm looking at in the browser.  Its a POST request, with the data payload very similar.  FYI, I'm using all four HTTP methods, PUT, POST, GET and DELETE with the same URL.  Finally, the reason I'm using a custom deserializer is that the controller mapped to the POST is not activating any breakpoints in the debugger.

Comment: The reason you're not getting breakpoints is that the issue is happening higher up. Set logging for `DispatcherServlet` to `DEBUG`.